# Pass variable from controller to javascript using PHP(Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have registration module and I already done so far the validation of all fields(fields are: name, email, username and password),check if the email and username is already existing.

And trying to add a suggestion if the username is already existing. I am done in adding a prefix in the username but having a problem to pass the variable to javascript and display it in my view

**This is my Controller**

```
$get_username = clean_data($_POST['username']);
$where = array(
"username"  => $get_username
);

$check_username = $this->Crud_model->count_result('username','users',$where);
if($check_username > 0)
{
    $fetch_username = $this->Crud_model->user_exists('users',$where);

    $last_username = strrev((int)strrev($fetch_username));  // returns last numeric value of username
    if($last_username){
    $count = count($last_username);//counts number of digit
    $str = substr($username, 0, -($count));;// subtract numeric value from last of username
}
$newstr = $last_username+1;

$username= $get_username.$newstr;
echo json_encode("existing");
// echo "var username = ". json_encode($username).";";

}
else
{
    $insert_user = array(
    'first_name'                => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['first_name'])),
    'last_name'                 => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['last_name'])),
    'profile_picture'           => "profile-picture.jpg",
    'username'                  => $get_username,
    'email'                     => $_POST['email'],
    'password'                  => hash_password($_POST['password']),
    'status'                    => 1,
    );

    $this->Crud_model->insert('users',$insert_user);


    echo json_encode("success");
}
```

**this is My javascript with ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#registration-form").on('submit',function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url+"formsubmit/new_form_submit",
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        if(result === "success")
        {
          $("h5").html("");
          success_message("#success-message-new-account","Create Successful!");
          window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url},2000);
        }
        else if(result === "existing")
        {
          $("h5").html("");
          success_message("#existing-message-account","You may use!".$username);
          // window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url},2000);
        }
        else{
          $("#first_name_error").html(result.first_name_error);
          $("#last_name_error").html(result.last_name_error);
          $("#username_error").html(result.username_error);
          $("#email_error").html(result.email_error);
          $("#password_error").html(result.password_error);
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
      }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

**This is my My View**

```
<div id="existing-message-account"></div>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">

    <input class="input100" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">

    <span class="label-input100">First</span>

</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">

    <input class="input100" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">

    <span class="label-input100">Last</span>

</div>
```

After the user fill up the registration form. It will be process in my javascript, now it will be check if the username registered is already existing or not. if it is not then it will be save in my table. If it is existing then it will add a number prefix.

**Example**

```
In my table users. I have existing username abcd, if the user register abcd then there would be a message "Username is already taken, you may use abcd1"
```

Question: How do I pass the variable $username into my javascript?

NOTE: I tried this approach, changing echo json_encode("existing"); into this echo json_encode($username). My javascript else if(result === $username)... The message will not work anymore.

Comment: use something like this : `$data = array('username' => $username,'status' => 'success'); echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Are you saying that changing this echo json_encode("existing"); into this echo json_encode($username)? If I did this in my javascript. else if(result === "existing").... wont work anymore. I tried also change result === $username, the message will not show

Comment: if u change your controller's code for response u have to also make changes in your ajax , see my answer for that , hope u will get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

For the `existing` status record do like this :

```
$data['username'] = $username;
$data['status'] = 'existing';
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

For the `success` status record return like this

```
$data['username'] = $username;
$data['status'] = 'success';
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Your ajax `success` part should have code like this :

```
  var result = JSON.parse(data);
  if(result.status === "success")
  {
    $("h5").html("");
    success_message("#success-message-new-account","Create Successful!");
    window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url},2000);
  }
  else if(result.status === "existing")
  {
    $("h5").html("");
    success_message("#existing-message-account","You may use!" + result.username);
    // window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url},2000);
  }
```

Comment: So thats how you access the element in javascript. result.<name of the element>. Am I correct?

Comment: yes this is the way for more : see  for `dataType` ;: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/